# Database of Swadesh lists

Tags: reference-request, comparative-linguistics, swadesh-list

Do anyone know where to find the most extensive collection of Swadesh lists?

And with how many different languages in the collection?

Comment: Dunno about 'most extensive', but have you seen [this collection](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Swadesh_lists)?

Comment: No, thanks for the tip:-) But I maybe hoped for a collection that was searchable, and where it is easy to see how many languages that are listed...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- [Wikipedia](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Swadesh_lists) (as another commenter already mentioned): 168 languages or language families.
- [Internet Archive: Rosetta Project: Swadesh Lists](http://archive.org/search.php?query=swadesh%20collection:rosettaproject): 1234 languages - the most extensive I know of (unless you wish to go and dig through primary literature).
- [Swadesh Lists for some less well-known languages](http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/main.cgi?root=new100): ca. 290 languages.

There seem to be only the raw lists, so if you want a searchable database you'll have to copy them together from those sources yourself.

Comment: Are the Rosetta project lists reliable?  @user66554

Comment: Those I checked seemed good enough to me, but I only checked a few because I don't speak most of them and thus am not qualified to judge: one would need a dictionary or at least some native speakers to check them, just like one would need to create them. So it comes down to either trusting the sources or checking the lists (whereas making your own from scratch would take more work and be less reliable). The more lists you check the more certain you can be of reliability, but you also need more time. It's up to you to decide how many you need to check before you trust the rest. @Midas

Comment: The Wikipedia (actually Wiktionary) list/category at the link above has been deleted. But it's here now: [permanent link 1](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Appendix:Swadesh_lists&oldid=42263455), [permanent link 2](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Category:Swadesh_lists_by_language&oldid=32817435). Of course nothing is permanent, but hopefully at least one of these links will continue to work for a while longer.

Answer (score 3):

Since it was not linked in the other answer,

- [IELex database](http://ielex.mpi.nl/)

Edit:

- [SIL.org](https://www.sil.org/resources/publications/search?query=Swadesh&sort_by=search_api_relevance&sort_order=ASC) also shares many Swadesh lists, some pdfs, xmls
- [panlex.org](https://dev.panlex.org/db/)

Edit 2:

- 171 languages in gdoc online at [kurdishdna.blogspot.com](http://kurdishdna.blogspot.co.at/2013/03/swadesh-list-of-indo-european-languages.html)

Edit 3:

- many indigenous American languages [ailla.utexas.org](http://www.ailla.utexas.org/search/search.html). Search for Wordlists. Mostly as mp3 or wav files.

@Flying did you ever get round to compiling those lists together?

Answer (score 1):

The [CLARIN Virtual Language Observatory (VLO)](https://vlo.clarin.eu/) has indexed a lot of Swadesh lists. Just enter "Swadesh list" in the search slit (or use this [bookmarked query](https://vlo.clarin.eu/search?q=swadesh%20list)) to get (at the moment of the writing) 1339 search hits to many different languages.

Comment: 1,429 results right now ... the number is slowly growing.